# How to use SelectMany in typescript

Tags: typescript, linq.js

I am getting this error and I am not sure why. I see that the `this.dayscalendar.Days` is a array with data. I am trying to use the `SelectMany` and select the one record that matches.

> linq.js:1521 Uncaught Error: Single:No element satisfies the condition.

```
Enumerable.From(this.dayscalendar.Days)
    ArrayEnumerable {source: Array(7)}
    source
    : 
    Array(7)
    0: {Day: 'Sun', IsSelected: false}
    1: {Day: 'Mon', IsSelected: false}
    2: {Day: 'Tues', IsSelected: false}
    3: {Day: 'Wed', IsSelected: false}
    4: {Day: 'Thus', IsSelected: false}
    5: {Day: 'Fri', IsSelected: false}
    6: {Day: 'Sat', IsSelected: false}
```

Line getting the error

```
Enumerable.From(this.dayscalendar.Days).SelectMany(w => w.day).Single(d => d.day === 'Wed');
```

Comment: Can it be because of wrong key? `0: {Day: 'Sun', IsSelected: false}` - Day with capital D. `SelectMany(w => w.day).Single(d => d.day )` - small d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Enumerable.From(this.dayscalendar.Days).Select(w => w.Day).Single(d => d === 'Wed');
```

If you want to get the whole object, you can apply Single directly as follows:

```js
Enumerable.From(this.dayscalendar.Days).Single(d => d.Day === 'Wed');
```

This will select the Day property from each item in dayscalendar.Days, then find the one that equals 'Wed'.

Also note that Single() will throw an error if there isn't exactly one element that satisfies the condition.

Comment: thanks when I do this I am not getting the object I should get that object record

Comment: Oh gotcha! I've updated my answer.